# Datatables Object ID

Tags: datatables, web2py

I have two tables and I am working with Datatables and what I would like to do is use the child row to show more information about a particular row. For example, on the table I will display first name, last name, username, and email and on the child or expandable row, I will show the nationality of that user.
The problem I am having is that when I expand the row, it shows only the id from the 'User' table and not the description associated to that id.
this is my first time dealing with Datatables so I don't have my experience with it.

Any suggestions to solve this issue?

```
db.define_table('User',
            Field('first_name', 'string'),
            Field('last_name', 'string'),
            Field('email','string'),
            Field('username','string'),
            Field('nationality','reference Nationality', requires = IS_IN_DB(db,db.Nationality.id,'%(description)s')
           )
db.define_table('Nationality',
            Field('description','string'),
            format = '%(descripcion)s'
           )
```

My controller

```
def user():
import json
usuario = json.dumps(db(db.auth_user.id>0).select().as_list())
return dict(formListar=XML(usuario))
```

//view//

```
<script>
var tabla;
$(document).ready(function(){
tabla=  $('#tablaGenerica').DataTable({
"data":  {{=formListar}},
                "scrollX": false,
                 "dom": 'lrtip',
                 "searching": true,
                 "sRowSelect": "single",
                  "columns": [
                              {
                                 "class":"details-control",
                                 "orderable":false,
                                 "data":null,
                                 "defaultContent": ""
                              },
                              { data: 'first_name' },
                              { data: 'last_name' },
                              { data: 'email' },
                              { data: 'username' },
                          ]
            });

 $('#tablaGenerica tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = tabla.row( tr );
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );

function format ( d ) {
        // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Nationality:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.nationality+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}
</script>



<table id="tablaGenerica" class="tablaC table-striped hover cell-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
  <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>First name</th>
         <th>Last name</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nationality` field in the `User` table is a `reference` field, which means it stores the associated record ID from the `Nationality` table, not the `description`. To include the `description` field from the `Nationality` table in your JSON, you'll need to do a join when fetching the data:

```
def user():
    usuario = db(db.User.nationality == db.Nationality.id).select().as_json()
    return dict(formListar=XML(usuario))
```

Note the `Rows` object has a built-in `as_json` method (a little more convenient, as it automatically handles special field types, such as dates and times).

When joining two tables, each record in the JSON array will include a separate object for each table. So, the JSON will look like:

```
[
  {
    "User": { "first_name": ..., "last_name": ..., ... },
    "Nationality": { "Description": ... }
  },
  ...
]
```

That means the columns specification for Datatables will have to change to:

```
{ data: 'User.first_name' },
{ data: 'User.last_name' },
{ data: 'User.email' },
{ data: 'User.username' },
```

Note, the `User.` prefix for each field, indicating nesting within the `User` object of the record.

Similarly, in the `format` function, access the nationality description via `d.Nationality.description` rather than `d.nationality`.